# Where would the get comment time function be?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the blank slate theme starter and I cant seem to find where to delete the function   its not in my comment.php or functions.php

my objective is to remove the at time from my comments list

Mr WordPress says:
February 15, 2014 ***at 3:04 am***

Hi, this is a comment.
To delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.

```
<?php if ( 'comments.php' == basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) return; ?>
<section id="comments">
<?php 
if ( have_comments() ) : 
global $comments_by_type;
$comments_by_type = &separate_comments( $comments );
if ( ! empty( $comments_by_type['comment'] ) ) : 
?>
<section id="comments-list" class="comments">
<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 ) : ?>
<nav id="comments-nav-above" class="comments-navigation" role="navigation">
<div class="paginated-comments-links"><?php paginate_comments_links(); ?></div>
</nav>
<?php endif; ?>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_comments( 'avatar_size=75' ); ?>
</ul>
<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 ) : ?>
<nav id="comments-nav-below" class="comments-navigation" role="navigation">
<div class="paginated-comments-links"><?php paginate_comments_links(); ?></div>
</nav>
<?php endif; ?>
</section>
<?php 
endif; 
if ( ! empty( $comments_by_type['pings'] ) ) : 
$ping_count = count( $comments_by_type['pings'] ); 
?>
<section id="trackbacks-list" class="comments">
<h3 class="comments-title"><?php echo '<span class="ping-count">' . $ping_count . '</span> ' . ( $ping_count > 1 ? __( 'Trackbacks', 'blankslate' ) : __( 'Trackback', 'blankslate' ) ); ?></h3>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_comments( 'type=pings&callback=blankslate_custom_pings' ); ?>
</ul>
</section>
<?php 
endif; 
endif;
if ( comments_open() ) comment_form();
?>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Rhys Stewart I edited the original post to include the referenced code file.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simple fix of removing a small function call and a bit of HTML from a page. Just got to find that page.

The functions to look out for are `comment_date()`, `get_comment_date()` and `get_comment_time()`. They should be in your functions.php file, and if not you will need to create a manual comments override function within your functions.php file.

By default the time/date is turned on and you will need to remove the code from the template.

**Example**

If you look in the WordPress base theme `twentyeleven`, in the functions.php file on like 528, the call is being made to show both the date and time. If you remove the code all about the time/date, then it will be removed on the theme.

Hope this makes sense to you.

Further reading + how to create custom comments design: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Comment: yea I have been looking for those functions just cannot find them in either one of those theme files. I also thought maybe I could use css display:none but there is no class around the time in the comment. I've seen the functions in the wordpress themes but I guess since I used blank slate to start this theme it isn't there. How could I override it in functions.php?